# Insert mysql column record to second table with different column name

Tags: mysql

I have a table called

**order**

```
| id | created | customer_id | ... | ... |
```

I would like to move the columns created and customer_id etc. with records to a second table called

**order_meta**

```
| id | order_id | meta | value |
```

so that the meta is *"created"* and value is *created value* from order's table

Is this possible to do with the mysql query or do I need to create an script for this?

Comment: Do you want to copy created, customer_id from order table to order_meta ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into order_meta (order_id, meta, value)
    insert id, 'created', created
    from orders;
```

If you want to denormalize more columns, you can do:

```
insert into order_meta (order_id, meta, value)
    insert id, m.meta,
           (case meta when 'created' then created
                      when 'customer_id' then customer_id
            end)
    from orders o cross join
         (select 'created' as meta union all
          select 'customer_id' as meta
         ) m
```

Comment: Kinda, but with this you need to it with all the records. I Am wondering if there is a way to do this in one query.

Comment: The last one is just what i wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO order_meta (order_id, meta, value) 

SELECT id, 'created', created

FROM order
```